# What effect does initial velocity have on the optimal incidence angle in projectile motion?

Tags: kinematics

(I am taking drag into account)

For the purposes of a physics paper that I am writing on projectile motion, I need to first determine whether changing the initial velocity has an impact on the 'optimal' (angle that gives the greatest range) angle of incidence. I have looked at some simulators that show that there is a slight change in the optimal angle depending on the speed of the projectile. However, I am uncomfortable allowing myself to dive into my paper just from a couple simulators which I have no idea what equations they are using to calculate the range. I've gotten into doing the calculations myself but they're getting hard so for now, I'd like to just ask anybody out there: is there relationship b/w the initial velocity and optimal angle? Thank you.

Comment: Post your equations - maybe we can help. It should be $45^{\circ}$ for constant initial speed versus the angle. Increasing the initial speed should always increase the range at a constant angle.

Comment: It is 45 degrees in a vacuum. When introducing drag, like I am, the optimal angle is no longer 45. Im not concerned with how increasing the initial speed will vary the range, I'm more concerned with whether increasing the initial speed varies the optimal angle. The drag equation is D = 1/2 Cd p A v^2 
p is density of fluid, Cd is the drag coefficient equal to 0.5, A is the cross-sectional area of the ball projectile. Problem is, the direction of the drag force is constantly changing and so it's hard to derive an equation that calculates the path of the projectile

Comment: Generally for simplicity drag Force due to a fluid is modelled as $ F = -kv $ if we set up some  DE 's we would be able to find equation of trajectories  and it turns out to be a little bit nasty with respect to representation of the terms. But on solving I  find that the maximal range is attained at infinite time . I can send a mail of the working if you want

Comment: My projectile is considered 'high-speed' so I learned that the drag force is equal to kv^2. And I'm confused as to what you mean by "infinite time". If I understand you correctly, that is not the case in my paper because the projectile will eventually return to a vertical displacement of 0 and hit the ground - so the flight time is finite. Thanks for replying btw :)

Comment: I'll try to solve using proportionality of $ v² $ .... But I want to suggest discuss an idea that rather than taking a single drag Force shouldn't we decompose it into two components by using the same proportionality law and try to approach the problem .... I will give this a try and then intimate you if any progress is achieved

Comment: What I found is that numerical method is what we need here as the differential equations can't be solved in a straight manner( or to put it we can't solve them or atleast i cant ) the linear model is indeed less accurate . I am just a student passed out of school recently please forgive if my talks seem rubbish

Comment: The way you model the atmosphere is a crucial piece of information needed to do 'optimal angle' type calculations. Do you model it as isothermal with constant density? Or do you model it using the so called "Standard Atmosphere"? Atmospheric density changes with altitude have a profound effect on optimal angle physics.

Comment: Yea, it can only be solved numerically using Euler's Method. I derived a set of equations for the displacement, velocity and acceleration in each component, but I assume that the air density remains the same, or 'isothermal'. Will this have noticeable effects even if I'm only firing a baseball at speeds of 50 km/h for example?